# how to do batch insert through MVC 3 And EF code-first

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, sql-server-express

I am trying to build a employee attendance sheet.
Here is my `AttendanceModel`

```
public class AttendanceModel 
{
    //Primary Key and auto-generated field for this model
    public int AttendanceID { get; set; }

    public DateTime AttendanceDate { get; set; }

    //Present/Absent status
    public bool Status { get; set;}

    //Primary key of Employee Model
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }

    //Reference to Employee Model
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }

}
```

Now I want this model to make a `View` containing `employeeId(Hidden field)` , Name of Employee and a checkbox for attendance.
**My problem is (Edited on 3rd day)**

1. Should i have to use a different ViewModel for this view
2. How to insert the information from `view` to the entity and ultimately to databse as it require more than one row to be inserted in the database (i.e Batch Processing)
3. I am also not getting how to retrieve the information from the view to do processing

Any suggestion is appreciable. :)
Thanks in Advance !!!
**EDIT (What i have tried) **
1. I have created another class `AttendanceViewModel` containing all the field of `AttendanceModel` except the reference to `Employee` model class. then in `view` I render it. In the controller the argument is `IEnumerable<AttendanceViewModel>` and from it populate the Attendance Model. Here is the code.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {            
        var EmployeeAttendance = from s in new EmployeeDBContext().Employees
                                select new AttendanceViewModel
                                {
                                    EmployeeID = s.EmployeeID
                                };
        return View(EmployeeAttendance.ToList());
    }
```

Controller Action to save the record is

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveAttendance(IEnumerable<AttendanceViewModel> attendancess)    // argument of SaveAttendance is always `null`
    {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var _context = new EmployeeDBContext();

                foreach (var a in attendancess)
                {
                    var newAttendance = new AttendanceModel
                    {
                        EmployeeID = a.EmployeeID,
                        AttendanceStatus = a.Status
                    };

                    _context.Attendance.Add(newAttendance);

                }
                _context.SaveChanges();
            }
           //Rest of code
```

But its not working argument is always `null` :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanna send additional information from view to controller you have to set the values to hidden input fields, like employeeId. Or you can store the additional properties in side memory by adding to Session object.

You have to use an `List<int> CheckedEmpIds` property in ViewModel. and in view you set the value of the employeeId to checkbox value.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="CheckedEmpIds" value="@Model.Employee.Id" />
```

when you submit the form, you can get the checked employee ids in action.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I have edited by question to make it more descriptive.I am really trying to wrap my head around batch processing and checkbox problem. thanks !!!